# Parse second/third page and add to list with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website for recipes and then present a page with a random pick.
For this I have made a piece of code that works perfect when I just get the first page, 35 recipes.
However: I want to grab the recipes from the 2nd and 3rd page as well. I figured I should write a loop for this but I can't seem to get it right. What did I do wrong in this code?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

# Create your views here.
def recipe(request):

#Create soup
    page = 0
    while page != 2:
        webpage_response = requests.get("https://www.ah.nl/allerhande/recepten-zoeken?page=" + str(page))
        webpage = webpage_response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")  
        recipe_links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class' : re.compile('^display-card_root__.*')})
        recipe_pictures = soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class' : re.compile('^card-image-set_imageSet__.*')})
        recipe_prep_time = [ul.find('li').text 
                   for ul in soup.find_all('ul',
                        attrs={'class': re.compile('^recipe-card-properties_root')})]


#Set up lists
        links = []
        titles = []
        pictures = []

#create prefix for link
        prefix = "https://ah.nl"

#scrape page for recipe
        for link in recipe_links:
            links.append(prefix + link.get('href'))

        for title in recipe_links:
            titles.append(title.get('aria-label'))

        for img in recipe_pictures:
            pictures.append(img.get('data-srcset'))

        page = page +1

#create random int to select a recipe
    nummer = random.randint(0,105)
    print(nummer)

#select correct link for image
    pic_url = pictures[nummer].split(' ')

#create context
    context = {
        "titles" : titles[nummer],
        "pictures" : pic_url[16],
        "preptime" : recipe_prep_time[nummer],
        "link" : links[nummer]
    }

#render page
    return render(request, "randomRecipe/recipe.html", context)
```

Comment: I assume your `while page != 2` is replaced by another statement in your actual implementation? Because that would obviously be a limiting factor in the number of pages you will be getting results from.

Comment: No, I only need the first three pages for this to work.

Comment: @Jelle Do you have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make pagination using `for loop`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

# Create your views here.
def recipe(request):

#Create soup
    for page in range(1,4):
        webpage_response = requests.get(f"https://www.ah.nl/allerhande/recepten-zoeken?page={page}" )
        webpage = webpage_response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")  
        recipe_links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class' : re.compile('^display-card_root__.*')})
        recipe_pictures = soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class' : re.compile('^card-image-set_imageSet__.*')})
        recipe_prep_time = [ul.find('li').text 
                   for ul in soup.find_all('ul',
                        attrs={'class': re.compile('^recipe-card-properties_root')})]


#Set up lists
        links = []
        titles = []
        pictures = []

#create prefix for link
        prefix = "https://ah.nl"

#scrape page for recipe
        for link in recipe_links:
            links.append(prefix + link.get('href'))

        for title in recipe_links:
            titles.append(title.get('aria-label'))

        for img in recipe_pictures:
            pictures.append(img.get('data-srcset'))

        

#create random int to select a recipe
    nummer = random.randint(0,105)
    print(nummer)

#select correct link for image
    pic_url = pictures[nummer].split(' ')

#create context
    context = {
        "titles" : titles[nummer],
        "pictures" : pic_url[16],
        "preptime" : recipe_prep_time[nummer],
        "link" : links[nummer]
    }

#render page
    return render(request, "randomRecipe/recipe.html", context)
```

Comment: This works perfect for scraping the other pages. However: I am trying to store the info in a list, like the recipe_links into the list links[]. I can't get this loop to store them all in a row. It only stores the last page scraped. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can use pandas DataFrame.  It would be better to create another question 
,if you feel complex . Thanks

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help!